# Can't turn on developer mode on Galaxy Tab S5e

Tags: samsung, settings, samsung-galaxy-tab, developer-options

Trying to turn developer mode on on this tablet of a client. I'm not familiar with it, I went here:

Settings -> About tablet -> Software Information -> Build Number

Tapping the build number does nothing. This is supposed to work on all Android devices too. No matter how many times I click on it nothing happens.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

insert sim card
disable the automatic time in android settings
set a date 7 days in future

Comment: https://forum.xda-developers.com/showpost.php?p=79547905&postcount=18

Answer (score 0):

Go to "accessibility", "Advanced settings", autorized "direct access" with "Dev tools". Activate it and now you are allowed to use "7 time" fonction