# How to turn off debugging in Android 10. Menu is missing developer options?

Tags: usb-debugging, developer-options

I have a bank application that won't run because it says something about Android Bridge and debugging over USB or something like that. I would love to share the exact message but it flips on and off screen so fast it's hard to read and I could barely make the above out after trying to start it repeatedly.

I found these instructions which would seem to exactly answer my problem:
https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/mem/intune/user-help/you-need-to-turn-off-usb-debugging-android

However, there is no "Developer options" under the System settings. Is there maybe some setting to turn on advanced configuration options somewhere that would make it appear that I'm overlooking?

Comment: Does it also appear if you disconnect the phone from the computer? And if the bank application is on your phone, then this question falls off the scope of SuperUser, and should be asked on android.stackexchange instead.

Comment: Which phone do you use (manufacturer and model name)? The used bank seems to be a bit outdated, Android ADB access was a potential security problem on Android before 4.2  as there was no access control, but since ADB on Android 4.2+ requires an authenticated PC in my opinion this no longer a reason to disable an app.

Answer (score 1):

Samsung? There is a bug where the dev options are hidden but enabled.

> To unhide the Developer options menu:
>
> 1. Go to "Settings", then tap "About device" or "About phone".
> 2. Scroll down, then tap "Build number" seven times.
>    Depending on your device and operating system, you may need to tap "Software information", then tap "Build number" seven times.
> 3. Enter your pattern, PIN or password to enable the Developer options menu.
> 4. The "Developer options" menu will now appear in your Settings menu.
>    Depending on your device, it may appear under Settings > General > Developer options.
> 5. To disable the Developer options menu, tap the switch.

[Samsung Support - How do I turn on the Developer Options menu on my Samsung Galaxy device?](https://www.samsung.com/uk/support/mobile-devices/how-do-i-turn-on-the-developer-options-menu-on-my-samsung-galaxy-device/)

Use another phone to take a video of the phone that has the problem. Then pause the video at the right moment and you can see the error message in all its glory.

Comment: Just a note that Developer options are normally hidden, and the quoted step is the standard process to enable it for the first time. However, it is also true that sometimes it's bugged, e.g. [Can't turn on developer mode on Galaxy Tab S5e](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/212796/44325)

Answer (score 1):

Settings > Build ops > tap 7x, every time you tap that, it will give a toast "you are `n` times away from being a developer" > final tap will show "you are a developer" > Settings options `Developer Option` will be seen.

Note that for getting the full benefit of `rooting`, you will also need to enable `OEM unlocking` option.